# why is Xamarin giving error with button Clicked?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

Basically I am getting this error
EventHandler "PressMeButton_Clicked" with correct signature not found in type "login.MainPage" (login)

login is the name of my project and login_Clicked is my clicked event handler

I'm trying to make a simple login page,and on the documentation I've seen various ways of Clicked working but everytime I try to write the method on the xaml.cs file when I compile it keeps giving the error above, if I remove the method it works.

```cs
  <Button x:Name="PressMeButton"
                Text="Press Me!"
                Pressed="PressMeButton_Pressed"
                Clicked="PressMeButton_Clicked" />
```

this is the XAML part you can see on Clicked the name I have for the event
and

```cs
 private void PressMeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as Button).Text = "I was just clicked!";
        }
```

So I expect to show me a text saying I was clickd but it does not even compile.

Comment: Does it work if you use `RoutedEventArgs` rather than `EventArgs`?

Comment: @mjwills it gives of an error that the type RoutedEventArgs could not be found when I switch

Comment: Can you add the compile-time error you are facing maybe? Because I reused your code I do not get any compile-time errors

Comment: I think that compilation not actual error just IDE intelligence issue, direct try to execute app in real device. Your code is correct.

Comment: @Ericaross try clean and build.

Comment: @Ericaross Thanks for accepting my answer. I am curious if you found this to be the actual solution, or if it was just a "this is a thing that can cause it so I'll accept it because it could help someone out." I mainly just posted because I hate finding identical problems with no answer that works for me. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question, but I ran into a similar issue. There was no good explanation why it would give the error. It would even happen on an empty handler that the IDE generated itself. I tried cleaning the solution, rebuilding, etc.

I found that there were some stuck build tasks going still. They appeared in the bottom bar that normally shows "Ready". For me, the solution was restarting VS. Once it started back up, and build worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

event handlers in the code-behind should be `protected`, not `private`

```
protected void PressMeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Text = "I was just clicked!";
}
```